# Python sorting html table

Tags: python, sorting, html-table

I am looping through a list of servers and connecting with OpenSSL, to retrieve the  SSL cert, and grabbing the server name, the date the cert expires, and calculating the number of days until cert expires. I am then building an html table with the data. The columns are Host, Hostname, Expiration Date, and Remaining Days. What is the best way to sort the table by the "Remaining Days" column?

```
# Update the hosts entry
    ssl_results[str(ip)][0] = host
    ssl_results[str(ip)][1] = server_name
    ssl_results[str(ip)][2] = exp_date
    ssl_results[str(ip)][3] = days_to_expire

    # Loop through the ssl_results entries and generate a email + results file
    try:

        # variable to hold html for email
        SSLCertificates = """<html>
                            <head>
                              <style>
                                    table{width: 1024px;}

                                    table, th, td {
                                        border: 1px solid black;
                                        border-collapse: collapse;
                                    }

                                    th, td {
                                        padding: 5px;
                                        text-align: left;
                                    }

                                    ul:before{
                                      content:attr(data-header);
                                      font-size:120%;
                                      font-weight:bold;
                                      margin-left:-15px;
                                    }
                                </style>
                              </head>
                            <body>
                              <p><h2>Blah, </h2>
                              <h3>SSL Expiration Summary:</h3>
                              <span style="color:red;"><b>Blah Blah Blah.<b></span><br><br>
                              <table id=\"exp_ssls\"><tr><th>Host</th><th>Hostname</th><th>Expiration Date</th><th>Remaining Days</th></tr>
                          """

        for entries in ssl_results:
            SSLCertificates += "<tr><td>" + str(entries) + "</td><td>" + str(ssl_results[entries][1]) + "</td><td>" + str(
                ssl_results[entries][2]) + "</td><td>" + str(ssl_results[entries][3]) + "</td></tr>"

        SSLCertificates += """</body>
                    </html>"""

        f = open('SSLCertificates.html', 'w')
        f.write(SSLCertificates)
        f.close()
        filename = 'SSLCertificates.html'
        attachment = open(filename, 'rb')
```

Comment: Put everything into a multi-dimensional list, then sort, then put it into the html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the dict before you form the html tags. then Iterate thru the dict and print it using html tags. Use sorted() to sort your dict before you iterate thru it.

```
import operator
x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

sorted_x will be a list of tuples sorted by the second element in each tuple. dict(sorted_x) == x.

Comment: Thanks Sekar. That worked. The code I used:                                                              sorted_results = sorted(ssl_results.items(),
                            key=lambda k: k[1]['days_to_expire'], reverse=False)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the results:)